# Ocultar y Mostrar un elemento css

Tags: css

se me presenta un problema que no consigo solucionar referente a la aplicacion del :hover para mostrar y ocultar div con display none. Anexo el codigo y describo la siutacion.

```
<body>
  <header class="site-header contenedor">
    <nav class="menu-area">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Menú<span class="arrow">&#x25BC;</span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-1">
              <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
              <li><a href="quienes-somos.html">Quienes Somos</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Musica</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Artistas</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Galeria<span class="arrow">&#x25B6;</span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-2">
                    <li><a href="">Fotos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Videos</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><img src="img/logo_vagabundos.png" alt="logo_principal" width="250px" height="80px"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Novedades</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav><!--Menú de navegación-->
  </header>

  <div class=" contenedor main-background ms">
      <div class="centrar-texto resaltar">
        <h1>MÚSICA</h1>
        <h2 class="fw-300">CONOCE LO QUE TENEMOS PARA TI</h2>
      </div>
  </div>

  <main class="contenedor seccion albumes">
    <div class="lista-albumes">
      <div><img src="img/portadas/portada1.jpg" width="200px" alt="portada_album"></div>
      <div><img src="img/portadas/portada2.jpg" width="200px" alt="portada_album"></div>
      <div><img src="img/portadas/portada3.jpg" width="200px" alt="portada_album"></div>
      <div><img src="img/portadas/portada4.jpg" width="200px" alt="portada_album"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="contenedor-desc">
      <div class="descripcion-album"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="lista-albumes">
      <div><img src="img/portadas/portada5.jpg" width="200px" alt="portada_album"></div>
      <div><img src="img/portadas/portada6.jpg" width="200px" alt="portada_album"></div>
      <div><img src="img/portadas/portada7.jpg" width="200px" alt="portada_album"></div>
      <div><img src="img/portadas/portada8.jpg" width="200px" alt="portada_album"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="contenedor-desc">
      <div class="descripcion-album"></div>
    </div>

  
  

  </main>
```

En el siguiente código, mediante el uso de css quiero ocultar el div.contenedor-desc y utilizando :hover sobre cualquier elemento de .lista-albumes mostrarlo nuevamente. Intente hacerlo de manera similar a como hice con el menu desplegable pero no me funcionó. Anexo a continuacion el codigo css

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%; /** Reset para REMS - 62.5% = 10px de 16px (1rem = 16px default)**/
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,*:before,*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.contenedor {
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 120rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.seccion {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  height: 30rem;
}
.centrar-texto {
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}
div.main-background {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 30rem;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
div.ms {
  background-image: url(../img/musica-background.jpg);
}
div.resaltar {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 21rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
div.resaltar h1 {
  margin-top: 1.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}


div.resaltar p {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/*Musica*/

main .lista-albumes {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

main .lista-albumes div:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s;
  border: solid 0.5rem #ff6347;
}

.contenedor-desc {
  display: none;
}

main .lista-albumes div:hover main > .contenedor-desc {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

main .descripcion-album {
  height: 25rem;
  border: solid 0.5rem #ff6347;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  border-radius: 1rem;
  width: 70%;
}
```

Dejo todo el codigo necesario. Estoy atento para cualquier posible solucion que pueda solucionar mi problema. Agradezco un monton

Comment: Excelentes respuestas. Ayuda increible

Answer (score 1):

Hay que tener en cuenta que en **CSS** solamente puedes interactuar o con hijos de un elemento o con hermanos posteriores, nunca con ancestros de un elemento o con sus hermanos anteriores.

Clarificado esto, podemos hacer algo para interactuar entre `.lista-albumes` y `.contenedor-desc` ya que son elementos hermanos y el queremos afectar a un hermano posterior al elemento que recibe el `hover`. Para ello usamos el selector `+`, que sirve para afectar al hermano inmediatamente posterior a un elemento, provocando que cada `.lista-albumes` tan solo afecte al `.contenedor-desc` que le corresponde.

```css
.contenedor-desc {
  color: red;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: none;
}

.lista-albumes:hover + .contenedor-desc {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<main class="contenedor seccion albumes">
  <div class="lista-albumes">
    <div><img src="img/portadas/portada1.jpg" width="200px" alt="portada_album"></div>
    <div><img src="img/portadas/portada2.jpg" width="200px" alt="portada_album"></div>
    <div><img src="img/portadas/portada3.jpg" width="200px" alt="portada_album"></div>
    <div><img src="img/portadas/portada4.jpg" width="200px" alt="portada_album"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="contenedor-desc">
    <div class="descripcion-album">Descripción 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="lista-albumes">
    <div><img src="img/portadas/portada5.jpg" width="200px" alt="portada_album"></div>
    <div><img src="img/portadas/portada6.jpg" width="200px" alt="portada_album"></div>
    <div><img src="img/portadas/portada7.jpg" width="200px" alt="portada_album"></div>
    <div><img src="img/portadas/portada8.jpg" width="200px" alt="portada_album"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="contenedor-desc">
    <div class="descripcion-album">Descripción 2</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Vaya! no sabia que con + eso era posible, muy buena respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Lastimosamente la única forma de afectar a otro elemento mediante la acción hover es si este elemento esta dentro del elemento principal, es decir, si contenedor-desc estuviese dentro de lista-albumes, entonces podrías hacer algo como esto.

```
.lista-albumes:hover > .contenedor-desc {
     display:block;
}
```

Otra forma seria mediante jQuery usando `toggleClass` y `hover`, esto no requiere que contenedor-desc este dentro de lista-albumes:

```
$(".lista-albumes").hover(function(){
  $(".contenedor-desc").toggleClass("show");
});
```

En tus CSS

```
.show {
  display: block!important;
}
```

Esto requiere agregar el script de jQuery  en tu header